# Add CSS File to Django Project - Nothing seems to work

Tags: python, css, django

I feel kinda tired of this problem right now, and am desperately looking for help.

I try to add a main.css file to my django project so I can do the CSS myself.

Watched like 8 full tutorials already and 6 of them crashed my project while the other 2 did not work.

So please is there anyone who really knows how to do this?

This must be a really simple thing i guess?

Im stuck on my project for 3 days now, so frustrating.

I hope to find a decent explanation of someone who really knows how this works.

[image: blabab]

[image: settings1]
[image: settings2]
[image: settings3]

[image: events]

[image: urls]

[image: urls2]

[image: structure]

Comment: please post related html file and from the browser the source code of the page in order to see how the html file has been rendered and sent to the browser. So you can see how the css file is being loaded and if it is successfull

Comment: how do you serve the project? runserver with DEBUG=True? Apache?

Comment: Please provide error and templates and structure of your project

Comment: @Razenstein ,  have added screenshots of the project in te question, hopefully it makes sense to you. still stuck on it

Comment: @Manoj Tolagekar, i added screenshot in this question, hopefully you could help me out

Comment: please add the posts as text/code, not as screen shots. Makes it easier to read and quote ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the templates folder in your project setting in DIRS []:
as

```
 'DIRS': [
        BASE_DIR / 'templates'
    ],
```

Comment: Claude Jacyo, i still got this error WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Answer (score 0):

1. the html content looks ok:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link .... href="{% static '/events/css/main.css' %}">
```

2. in order to see were {% static /events/css/main.css %} is resolved to

   a) just put it in the body section of the html so that you can see it as a string

```
{% block content %}

xxxx{% static '/events/css/main.css' %}yyyy    <!-- xxx and yyy just there to show if {} delivers an empty string

{% endblock content %}
```

b) in your browser open "document source" to see the html code href="...".

Should be

```
"http://localhost:8000/static/events/css/main.css"
```

... once the target {% static .. %} is clear you can continue next debugging step. There is different approaches possible to debug. IMO it is most straight forward to look on the final doc -> see the final result of rendering the page -> modify tags etc if wrong.

You could also start looking on all settings.py definitions - but that is a little guessing around what is wrong.

Comment: I did what you asked me to and received the following error when trying to runserver:  Could not parse the remainder: '/events/css/main.css' from '/events/css/main.css'

Comment: make sure you have correct syntax {% static '/events/css/main.css' %}. This error looks like you have {% static /events/css/main.css %}

Answer (score 0):

Try this to join your BASE_DIR to static

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Comment: @ Kartikey Sinha, already done, i received an error, so i also tried: STATIC_URL = 'events/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'event/static')             ,, after that when runserver, i got no error anymore, but also it is not working, the CSS

Comment: I dont get it, why would they make it so hard to use CSS in Django? Is there maybe another option for me thats easier, how about Flask for example??

Comment: @HeliasMarketing You didn't get any error right ? did you try just writing '/static/' , well it also depends upon the value of BASE_DIR tho, also it wasn't clear to can you write it again what you tried for STATICFILES_DIRS , was it just same or something else?